# Audit log tracking Request / Response body in Spring boot application

Tags: audit-logging

What is best approach to write all the request/response (including request/response body) in to log file in spring boot Rest application.Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HandlerInterceptor` interface, but the response body is not accessible through it. You need something which can access the response before it is committed. So you should implement the `ResponseBodyAdvice<Object>` Interface and override the `beforeBodyWrite` method.